# Cramer distance vs. Wasserstein distance: Which one is stronger or not compatible?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Consider the space $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. The $p$-order Cramer distance $l_p$ ($p \geq 1$) is defined by

$$
l_p(\mu, \nu) = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_{\mu}(x) - F_{\nu}(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}
$$
for all $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ where $F_{\mu}$ and $F_{\nu}$ denote the (cummulative) distribution functions of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

The $p$-order Wasserstein distance is defined by 
$$
W_p(\mu, \nu) = \left( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |x-y|^p d\pi(x,y) \right)^{1/p},
$$
where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ denotes the set of all Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$.

It is known that $W_1 = l_1$ (via their dual forms). But for $p > 1$, are these two metrics $W_p$ and $l_p$ compatible or at least could we bound one by the other in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same question! Yet, I haven't found anything else than this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10743.pdf) that says without references in section 4.1

> The $l_p$ and Wasserstein metrics are identical at $p = 1, but are otherwise distinct

Comment: It is well known that they are identical for p = 1 (because for p = 1, W_p has a dual form and that dual form is the same as the dual form of l_1). I think that W_p and L_p are not compatible in general for p > 1 (I recall that I checked that by constructing the distances for two Gaussians for p =2 (these distances have closed-forms and not identical))